# Cannot call Invoke or BeginInvoke on a control until the window handle has been created

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, invoke

Hi 
I googled this but I did not realy find too much
Here is my situation I Have ListBox and I enabled drag and drop option
I add an background worker to do for me somework
Well When I drag and drop first time evry thing go ok
When I drag and drop seconod time I have that problem

Here is my code

```
 if (imageListBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                imageListBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                    try
                    {
                        imageListBox.Items.Remove(fileInf.Name); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Form2 frm = new Form2();
                        IntPtr a = frm.Handle;
                        imageListBox.Items.Remove(fileInf.Name); 
                    }

                }));
            }
```

Form this block

```
catch (Exception)
                        {
                            Form2 frm = new Form2();
                            IntPtr a = frm.Handle;
                            imageListBox.Items.Remove(fileInf.Name); 
                        }
```

I've add it when I got the problem but it sem that it does not solve the problem

Any help please ?thanks

Comment: Why in the world are you creating a new form in the `catch` block? How is a user going to be able to drag and drop on a form that doesn't exist? And if the form already exists, why do you need to create a new one? This is either really misguided code, or you need to clarify more about your design. And either way, guaranteed that's your problem—read the error message you're getting, it's pretty clear.

Comment: It might be easier to get the process id and use the Process.WaitForExit method --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx

Comment: @hjb417: Why would you expect that to work? The code shown in the question doesn't spawn a new process. What process ID would you get?

Comment: Well the catch code I add it to try to solve the problem I thought it could help me